# Formik values are not initialising from data with API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, formik

I am using Formik and I can initialise the values of the form by doing the following

```
 const formik = useFormik({
   initialValues: {
   name: "test",
   bio: "my bio text",
   email: "me at email",
   country: { name: "Australia", code: "AU" },
 },
   enableReinitialize: true,
    validationSchema: Yup.object({
      name: Yup.string().required("Name is required"),
      email: Yup.string()
        .email("Invalid email address")
        .required("Email is required"),
      date: Yup.date().required("Date is required").nullable(),
      country: Yup.object({
        name: Yup.string(),
        code: Yup.string(),
      }).required("Country is required"),
    }),

    onSubmit: (data) => {
      signupUser(data);
    },
  });
```

However if I try to initialise the values from an api call that is made as part of a useEffect, it doesn't work.  In the example below I'm not actually using the exact values returned from the API, I've hard coded them to be exactly the same as the working example.

For example.

```
  const [initialValues, setInitialValues] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    countryservice.getCountries().then((data) => setCountries(data));
    const countrynames = countries.map((x) => x.name);
    api.post("/api/profile", { username: user.username }).then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
      setInitialValues({
        name: "test",
        bio: "my bio text",
        email: "me at email",
        country: { name: "Australia", code: "AU" },
      });
    });
  }, []); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

  console.log(initialValues);

  const formik = useFormik({
   initialValues: { initialValues },
   enableReinitialize: true,
    validationSchema: Yup.object({
      name: Yup.string().required("Name is required"),
      email: Yup.string()
        .email("Invalid email address")
        .required("Email is required"),
      date: Yup.date().required("Date is required").nullable(),
      country: Yup.object({
        name: Yup.string(),
        code: Yup.string(),
      }).required("Country is required"),
    }),

    onSubmit: (data) => {
      signupUser(data);
    },
  });
```

Comment: Can you please replicate this on some online [sandboxes](https://codesandbox.io/)? I can guess the issue but that may not be beneficial.

Comment: ok I'll try to do that, its probably going to take a couple of days to work out how to though

Comment: Why do you want to change the initialValues? Why not change the values itself after API call?

Comment: @user1768233 in that case try directly passing initialValue. SOmething like: `const formik = useFormik({initialValues: initialValues, // ...rest` and render the form only after `initialValue` is set `
`return initialValues ? (
  <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
    {/* Your form fields go here */}
  </form>
) : null;`

Comment: thanks, I replied before I had seen or you updated your complete response.. so initialValues: initialValues, doesn't work. However if I break it down like this  "initialValues: { name: initialValues.name ,bio: initialValues.bio, email: "", date: null, country: null, accept: false}," it does...

Comment: @user1768233 That is not the issue. Did you use `return initialValues ? (   <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>     {/* Your form fields go here */}   </form> ) : null;`? Anyways if you're able to solve it. All good:)

Comment: ok, its not working as I thought it did... I'll have to try to replicate it on a sandbox. thanks of your help so far.